# Does “Client-only Framework subset" not include client application services?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, client

After recently discovering how insanely long the .net 3.5 framework was to install I searched for and found what I thought was a solution - the 'client only framework subset'.

This claims to include WPF etc, all the typical things required by 'Client Applications'.

Our application makes use of Client Application Services

(see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx)

Unfortunately it seems that the "Client only subset" doesn't inlucde such things as System.Web.ClientServices.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm gathering, the Client Application Services are not included in the [Client Profile Preview](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-intro-client-profile.aspx).  The reason why, I think, is because the Client Profile Preview is designed to deploy a smaller subset of the .NET framework to be used by client applications.  The Client Application Services entail using a series of ASP.NET technologies.

However, the ASP.NET technologies are not included in the Client Profile Preview, probably because ASP.NET technologies were not deemed to be something client applications would use since ASP.NET is a web application framework.  Unfortunately, with Client Application Services you're kind of in a gray area between a typical client application and ASP.NET.

Comment: So ridiculous with all this cross over between technologies and naming etc.

"Client only subset" which is for "Client applications" doesn't include libraries for "client application services". Thanks MS.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, it is ludicrous that LINQ is NOT included either!   They claim it is for Client apps using WCF, but data maniuplation and queries using LINQ was not considered?  WTF?

This makes Client Subset USELESS in our development.  The sad part is that this was a perfect solution for our embedded application due to the reduced footprint.

Way to go again MS!